# Cannot Publish after Data Dump | Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess

Tags: publishing, publishingfailed, oracle-12c

#### Background

Using an `Oracle 12c 64-bit client` from [Oracle client software (ODAC) version 12.1.0.1 64-bit from Oracle website](http://download.oracle.com/otn/other/ole-oo4o/ODAC121010_x64.zip).

#### Situation

I have just performed a data restoration from a higher to one of my lower environments within DTAP. Everything restored properly - after eyeball test within the TCM - and I have reset my publication targets in the CME specific to the new refreshed environment. However, when I begin to republish all or one piece of content I get this error:

```
Unable to publish item(s) with id
Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've looked online at some reasons why this is happening, but none seem to be specific to my scenario as when I compare environments. I am not missing/blocked files or `.dlls` and haven't found this to be tridion specific, yet..

When I view [Setting up Oracle client software](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-19199E60-4989-4F63-82AC-92B588A46590?#) I see:

12. Open a command prompt and access the bin\ subdirectory of the Oracle home directory or home directories and execute the following command: `tnsping.exe myoracleserver`- *does not exist; but does not exist in any other environments either* - [tnsping](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/tnsping-101/)
13. Check the folder `c:\Windows\assembly` for the presence of a number of new assemblies called `Oracle.DataAccess` or `Policy.2.111.Oracle.DataAccess` (the number may differ) - *these do not exist; but they do not exist in any other environments either*

Has anyone ran into this kind of error before with Tridion? It only happens when I begin to publish.

Event Viewer:

```
Unable to Initialize TDSE object.
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Error Code:
0x80040000 (-2147221504)

Call stack:
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Oracle.OracleDatabaseUtilities.GetConnection()
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Oracle.OracleDatabaseUtilities..ctor()
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Oracle.OracleDataSession..ctor()
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean&,RuntimeMethodHandleInternal&,Boolean&)
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,StackCrawlMark&)
 System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,StackCrawlMark&)
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type,Boolean)
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.DataSessionFactory.CreateDataSession()
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.DataSessionFactory.CreateDataSession(UserData)
Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetDataSession()
Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String,IEnumerable`1,IEnumerable`1)
Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String,String)
Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor(String,String)
Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.SystemFacade.InitializeUserContext(UserContext,String,String)
UtilitiesTDS.GetUserContext
TDSE.Initialize


Component: mscorlib
Errorcode: 0
User: XXX\MTSUSER
```

Comment: few links you can refer: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5456/failed-upgrade-from-sdl-tridion-2011-sp1-hr2-to-tridion-2013-sp1 
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/178312/Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-Oracle-DataAccess

Comment: Do you have the Oracle.DataAccess.dll assembly in \web\WebUI\WebRoot\bin and is it version 4.112.3.0?

Comment: Also, do you have any outscaled publishers running on a different machine? If it only happens when you publish, it could be because it's picked up on a different machine that happens to be missing this assembly now.

Comment: @RajKumar I have viewed those 2 specific links prior to posting this here on TSE, so definitely good to know we are on the same page and I am headed down correct path. However; in an effort keep all environments identical, really wondering why I need to go that route.. My other restoration, in a even lower env were clean and did not require that..hmm

Comment: @PeterKjaer Yes. That's the version of my Oracle.DataAccess.dll but it resides in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.121.1.0__89b483f429c47342` I could move it over, and I think that's what the links Raj is referring too mention; however, strange to need to do this since no others have Oracle.DataAccess.dll assembly in \web\WebUI\WebRoot\bin there either. No. no outscaled publishers at the moment. I'm just on a mission to keep all environments the same (if possible) Ill keep comparing, and report back my output once its working one way or another to this thread.

Comment: If it's in the GAC you should not need it anywhere else. You could try using Fusion Log Viewer to see how the assembly is being accessed and by what.

Comment: TNSPING.EXE doesn't exist in newer versions, you can asses your conection with telnet, it's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tridion had a [Legacy pack installed](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5779/oracle-client-requirements-for-sdl-tridion-2013-sp1). Thus, `Oracle ODAC 64-bit` would not allow me to publish and (presumably) caused the error. 
1. Removed Legacy pack from Tridion installation - after I installed and verified it would not work by simply installing the 32-bit ODAC Oracle client. 
2. Then I removed both 32-bit & 64-bit versions of Oracle ODAC client via Universal uninstaller + *[and everything Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83967/how-do-i-do-a-manual-uninstall-of-oracle)* 
3. Dropped schemas `Tridionbroker_Live, Session, Stage` 
4. Reinstalled Oracle 64-bit ODAC 
5. Re-ran `.\Install Content Data Store.ps1`successfully and rebuilt schemas `Tridionbroker_Live, Session, Stage` 
6. Then uninstalled Tridion 2013 SP1
7. Reinstalled Tridion 2013 SP1
8. Installed HR1 and can now publish successfully!

Comment: Now that's a lot of work. The legacy pack does need 32 bit oracle, and there is a special order in which it needs to be installed - I think it's 32 bit first, then 64 bit, it's documented somewhere. Glad to hear it's working now!